# NSG rule configuration using powershell – having trouble with importing ASGs

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am in the process or writing a powershell script to configure NSG rules. Most of the rules contain IP addresses as the source but some others source are defined by ASGs. My script works ok if the source is an IP address but throws out an error if the source is an ASG.

The error message is as follows.

> Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig : Cannot bind parameter
>   'SourceApplicationSecurityGroup'. Cannot convert the "xxxx-fw-asg"
>   value of type "System.String" to type 
>   "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSApplicationSecurityGroup".

As per the error message, the script expects the ASG in a certain data type while actually it is a string.
I could not find a way to convert this string to the type that Powershell expects.
Appreciate any help to convert the data type ( or to resolve this by any other way ).

```
$nsgCsv = Import-Csv .\NSG-rule-list.csv

foreach ($rule in $nsgCsv) {
    if ($rule.SourceAddressPrefix) {            
        Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name  $rule.NSG -ResourceGroupName $rule.resourceGroup | Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
            -Name $rule.ruleName `
            -Description $rule.Description `
            -Access $rule.Access `
            -Protocol $rule.Protocol `
            -Direction $rule.Direction `
            -priority $rule.Priority `
            -SourceAddressPrefix ($rule.SourceAddressPrefix -split ',') `
            -SourcePortRange * `
            -DestinationAddressPrefix ($rule.DestinationAddressPrefix -split ',') `
            -DestinationPortRange ($rule.DestinationPortRange -split ',') `
        | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup           
    }
    else {            
        Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name  $rule.NSG -ResourceGroupName $rule.resourceGroup | Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
            -Name $rule.ruleName `
            -Description $rule.Description `
            -Access $rule.Access `
            -Protocol $rule.Protocol `
            -Direction $rule.Direction `
            -priority $rule.Priority `
            -SourceApplicationSecurityGroup  $rule.sourceASG `
            -SourcePortRange * `
            -DestinationAddressPrefix ($rule.DestinationAddressPrefix -split ',') `
            -DestinationPortRange ($rule.DestinationPortRange -split ',') `
        | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup         
    }
}
```

Following is the CSV content

```
resourceGroup,NSG,ruleName,Description,Protocol,SourcePortRange,DestinationPortRange,SourceAddressPrefix,sourceASG,DestinationAddressPrefix,DestinationASG,Access,Priority,Direction
poc-network-rg,poc-dmz-nsg,Test7,test rule 7,TCP,*,443,,tes-fw-asg,192.168.0.0/24,NA,Allow,609,inbound
```

Answer (score 0):

For the -SourceApplicationSecurityGroup , you need to get the ASG and refer it here.

Sample:

$srcAsg = New-AzureRmApplicationSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup -Name srcAsg -Location "West US"

{
        Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name  $rule.NSG -ResourceGroupName $rule.resourceGroup | Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig 
            `-Name $rule.ruleName`
            -Description $rule.Description 
            `-Access $rule.Access`
            -Protocol $rule.Protocol 
            `-Direction $rule.Direction`
            -priority $rule.Priority 
            `-SourceApplicationSecurityGroup  $srcAsg`
            -SourcePortRange * 
            `-DestinationAddressPrefix ($rule.DestinationAddressPrefix -split ',')`
            -DestinationPortRange ($rule.DestinationPortRange -split ',') `
        | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
    }